# Проблема с разметкой. Веса в LinearLayout

Tags: android, java

Разметка моей главной активности:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/gvMain">
</GridView>

<it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/hlvMain"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Так вот, несмотря на то, что для GridView присвоен вес 1, а для HListView не присвоен (т.е. 0), GridView вдавливается куда-то в небо (адаптер присвоен одинаковый).

```
public void setData(DataParadigma data){
    this.data = data;
    adapterAd = new AdapterAd(this, data.ads);

    hlvMain.setAdapter(adapterAd);
    gvMain.setAdapter(adapterAd);
}
```

а выглядит так - [тык](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/3_10_2014/10/93LDiaHAEyVrdokFhcS4A.jpg).

**update:**
А если жестко задать высоту, то отображается нормально:

```
 <GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="159dp"

    android:id="@+id/gvMain"/>

<it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:id = "@+id/hlvMain"
    />
```

внешний вид - http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/3_10_2014/10/r6dn1lq1ykCRjtaiXZejqQ.jpg

Comment: В обеих вьюхах ставьте вес в 1.

Comment: @monomi, Зачем? Тогда они поделят пространство пополам ведь.  
http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/3_10_2014/11/H1eBZmh0L0yIVysqnD5ghg.jpg

Comment: У Вас разве не выводится предупреждение: Use a layout_height of 0dp instead of match_parent for better performance

Comment: @woesss, "Используйте layout_height = "0dp" вместо match_parent"? Нет, не выводит. Напротив, предупредит, что тогда вью будет невидимым. Вообще, странно было бы иначе.